# How can I extract only numbers from a string using Google Data Studio RegEx?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to extract only the numbers from a string; for example:

```
+36,145
```

Expected result:

```
36145
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chart-level fields, adding the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function and setting the field `AS NUMBER` ensures that it can be aggregated as required, when set as a metric ([`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) defaults to a *TEXT* field):

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(X, "(\\+|,)", "") AS NUMBER )
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c4e4f39c-565e-4225-8c07-8c296b486797) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(X, ' *\\+|,,*', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10496674#:~:text=not%20digits%20(%E2%89%A1%20[^0-9])](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10496674#:%7E:text=not%20digits%20(%E2%89%A1%20%5B%5E0-9%5D)), the simplest way to remove all non-digit characters is with `\D` in the pattern.  No piping is necessary in the pattern.  Writing a "one or more" quantifier (`+`) after the non-digit metacharacter will allow the regex engine to make longer matches and therefore fewer replacements. If you need the output to be cast as a number do this after mutating the value.

```
CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(X, R"\D+", "") AS NUMBER)
```